# Constructing Euler's Method in a simple way using Python

Tags: python

I need to write a really simple function for Euler's Method in Python.

I want to do it by giving the following inputs:

a function f of x,y such that y'=f(x,y)

(x0,y0): starting point

Dx: step size

n: number of iterations

My problem is that I am not sure how to make the computer understand something like f(i)= e.g. 2*i inside my iteration. I have already written a code which does not work(obviously). The f function should be given as a lambda function. I would also like the result to have 4 decimals.

```
from math import *
def euler(f,x(0),y(0),Dx,n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        x(i)=x(i-1)+Dx
        y(i)=y(i-1)+Dx*f(x(i-1),y(i-1))
        print(i,' ',x(i),' ',y(i))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to label the stages of `x` and `y` explicitly; you'll just overwrite their old values at each step:

```
def euler(f, x, y, Dx, n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        x, y = x + Dx, y + dx*f(x,y)
        print("{}: {:.4f} {:.4f}".format(i, x, y))
```

Using `x, y = ...` ensures that both calculations are performed with the current values of `x` and `y` before overwriting the names with their new values. Without that feature, you would need a temporary variable to preserve the old value of `x`.

```
def euler(f, x, y, Dx, n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        new_x = x + Dx
        y = y + Dx * f(x, y)
        x = new_x
        print("{}: {:.4f} {:.4f}".format(i, x, y))
```